# Cannot add ASP.NET MVC 5 Controller to simple ASP.NET MVC project in VS2013

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

To reproduce:
1) In VS 2013 Update 5, create a solution by selecting "ASP.NET Web Application" from  Installed > Templates > Visual C# > Web.  Make sure .NET Framework 4.5.1 is selected.
2) In the New ASP.NET Project dialog that appears, select 'Empty' and check the MVC option.  Click OK.
3) When the solution is ready, build it.
4) Right-click on the Controllers folder in Solution Explorer and select Add > Controller...
5) In the Add Scaffold dialog, select 'MVC 5 Controller - Empty' and click Add.
6) In the Add Controller dialog, change the name to HomeController and click Add.  I get the following error message (and no Controller):
Error
There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Failed to render template because of the following errors:
'Compiling transformation: 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.TextTransformation.Errors' is not supported by the language' at line number '60' and column number '14', 'Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'TypeDescriptor' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)' at line number '73' and column number '87', 'Compiling transformation: The type or namespace name 'TypeDescriptor' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ComponentModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)', ....
And the error text continues the same way several more times, with the same TypeDescriptor problem description, except the line numbers reported are 106, 139 and 172.
I added a reference to System.ComponentModel.dll (from the GAC) without success.  I have also tried generating the project by selecting the 'MVC' template in step 2 above and adding another controller; same error.  I also deleted the PendingDeletions entries from the registry; cleaned my local appdata; repaired, uninstalled and reinstalled VS2013, all without luck.  Any other ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have recently updated to VS2013 update 5 and your process works for me. Perhaps your templates have been corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same error in an ASP.NET Web API 2 application in Visual Sudio 2013. Here is a workaround that I am using:

```
1.) Right click folder where you want to create controller
2.) Click Add
3.) Click New Item
4.) Expand Visual C#, Expand Web
5.) At this point I click Web API Controller Class (v2.1)
```

This worked for me, but right clicking on the folder, choosing Add, Controller gives the error.